# Embed multiple ints in byte array

Tags: c++, serialization

I am using this code:

```
int number; //=smth
unsigned char sendBuffer[255];
sendBuffer[0] = number & 0xFF;
sendBuffer[1] = (number  >> 8) & 0xFF;
sendBuffer[2] = (number  >> 16) & 0xFF;
sendBuffer[3] = (number  >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

to put `number` in byte array `sendBuffer`.

My question is:

1. Say I want to embed now two numbers in the byte array, shall I proceed like this?

   ```
   sendBuffer[0] = number & 0xFF;
   sendBuffer[1] = (number  >> 8) & 0xFF;
   sendBuffer[2] = (number  >> 16) & 0xFF;
   sendBuffer[3] = (number  >> 24) & 0xFF;
   sendBuffer[4] = number2 & 0xFF;
   sendBuffer[5] = (number2  >> 8) & 0xFF;
   sendBuffer[6] = (number2  >> 16) & 0xFF;
   sendBuffer[7] = (number2  >> 24) & 0xFF;
   ```

   **Will this work even if** `number` **is of size say 8 or 6 bytes?**
   (I am saying this because on some platforms the int maybe 4 bytes or 6 right?
   So I was thinking if the above code also works when number is 6 bytes?
   Further thing to note is that even if it is 6 bytes, but I only
   store 4 byte integer inside it, will above code work?).

   This buffer I usually store on some memory of a card and I don't have problems reading it back (e.g., endiannes etc. issues, the byte array when reading seems to come in the order I saved).
2. Finally, how to reconstruct the integer from the byte array `sendBuffer`?

Comment: This is one of the cases where `memcpy` on POD types or primitives is allowed. Look at protobuf, Boost Serialization or Boost Spirit, though

Comment: As this is C++ you should go with `std::copy` (which will internally almost always use `memcpy` or `memmove` for POD types).

Comment: I didn't read your question too closely so forgive me if this is irrelevant, but perhaps std::bitset could be of use to you?

Comment: I wrote a utility for exactly this purpose as port of a project: https://github.com/barbu110/data-compresion/blob/master/lib/utils/include/utils/bytes.h .  I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, proceed like that. No, it only works for 4 bytes.

There is a easier, better way to do this, although it can cause endianness issues if the buffer is sent from one computer to another which uses a different architecture. Assuming you know the type of `number`, overlay another array on top of `sendBuffer`.

```
unsigned char sendBuffer[255];
number_type *sendBufferNum = (number_type*) sendBuffer;
sendBufferNum[0] = number;
sendBufferNum[1] = number2;
```

Reading a number can be done the same way.

```
unsigned char receiveBuffer[255];
//read values into receiveBuffer
number_type *receiverBufferNum = (number_type*) receiveBuffer;
number_type number = recieveBuffer[0];
number_type number2 = receiveBuffer[1];
```

Comment: What if I use this: `*(int*)(sendBuffer + pos) = some_int;`
? where some_int is of known type. Say int32_t

Comment: Yup, that does effectively the same thing. Just note that the second integer will be sendBuffer+4, and the next one sendBuffer+8.

Comment: Yes I am embedding several integers using that method now, thanks.

Comment: Also I just read a bit of your post I missed the first time.
"I am saying this because on some platforms the int maybe 4 bytes or 6 right?"
#include<stdint> allows you to use fixed-size ints. int<size>_t and uint<size>_t, where 'size' is in bytes, will /always/ be the same size.

Comment: Yes that is why I am using int32_t. Actually my code is smth like this: `*(int32_t*)(sendBuffer + 0) = some_int; *(int32_t*)(sendBuffer + 4) = some_int2;` Looks ok?

Comment: Yup, that should work fine. You just have to be certain that both the sending and receiving computers use the same endianness. Generally, all Intel made processors are little-endian, so as long as it's just Intel to Intel, you'll be totally fine. If you do need to go from one architecture to another, you may need to use one of the other answers.

Comment: Actually I am storing the sendBuffer on smart card. I didn't have issues so far. It returns the byte array in the order I stored ..

Comment: The endianness problem isn't to do with how it's stored on the card, but how the computer internally stores integers. With the above way, it is stored however the computer that is writing it stores integers internally. The one that that reads the data will interpret it as the way it internally stores integers. But in most cases, both computers should store them the same, so it's really not an issue. The only place where it can crop up is embedded programming, since a lot of microprocessors use big endian, while a lot of desktop processors (i.e. Intel made) use little endian.

Comment: I agree I think you got the point right. Even if my computer stores ints in big endian, then the catch is to interpret the data correctly, right? (because it will be written to the card in the way I **wrote** it to the card)

Comment: Yep, exactly. Like I said though, you shouldn't need to worry about it in most cases. Just remember the problem exists, and if 32 suddenly becomes some really big number for no obvious reason, that's possibly the cause.

Comment: casting `sendBuffer` to `number_type*` is a bad idea if you don't know about the alignment. On x86 it's allowed although slower, but it's forbidden on most other architectures

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work even if number is of size say 8 or 6 bytes?

It works but obviously you need to add more lines to save all the bytes in the value. That's **a lot** of manual work which is not very extensible. Use a programmatic approach instead

```
auto num = number;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(number); i++, num >>= CHAR_BIT)
    sendBuffer[i] = number & 0xFF;
```

But why do that when you already have [`memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy)? This way you need only **1 line**, and even better, it can be **extended to multiple values easily**

```
memcpy(&sendBuffer[0],               number1, sizeof number1);
memcpy(&sendBuffer[sizeof(number1)], number2, sizeof number2);
```

---

> Finally, how to reconstruct the integer from the byte array sendBuffer?

Easy. Just shift the bytes back

```
number  = (sendBuffer[3] << 24) | (sendBuffer[2] << 16) | (sendBuffer[1] << 8) | sendBuffer[0];
number2 = (sendBuffer[7] << 24) | (sendBuffer[6] << 16) | (sendBuffer[5] << 8) | sendBuffer[4];
```

Again, avoid tedious work like that and use a `for` loop

```
number = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(number); i++)
    number = (number << 8) | sendBuffer[i];
```

But `memcpy` also works and is highly recommended

```
memcpy(&number, &sendBuffer[numberIndex], sizeof number);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This only works for 32bit (4 bytes) integer. You have to write a 64bit (8 bytes) version if you are going to support large int.
2. You can reverse the process using bitwise OR.

   ```
   #define BigEndianGetUInt32(ptr)  ( ((uint32)((uint8*)(ptr))[0]) << 24 | \  
                                      ((uint32)((uint8*)(ptr))[1]) << 16 | \  
                                      ((uint32)((uint8*)(ptr))[2]) <<  8 | \  
                                       (uint32)((uint8*)(ptr))[3]) )
   number  = BigEndianGetUInt32(sendBuffer);
   number1 = BigEndianGetUInt32(sendBuffer+4);
   ```

As a side note, if you're serializing data just for the same device, you could have memcpy'ed `number` to `sendBuffer`.

```
memcpy(sendBuffer, &number, sizeof(number));
memcpy(sendBuffer+sizeof(number), &number1, sizeof(number1));
```

Comment: what if the integer is 6 bytes, but I know I will always store only 4 byte value inside it - will my code work in such case?

Comment: If you're going to store an integer with 6 bytes (48 bits) of significant bits, you would have to use a 64 bits large integer. It's either 4 or 8 bytes, there is no middle ground.